# RxSwift: CombineLatest endless stream of identical values

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm seeing an endless stream of identical events being sent to combineLatest, even though the individual observables only print two values: the initials, and the ones I set. I need to explicitly do `distinctUntilChanged()` to stop the cycle, but I don't understand why.

```
let one = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: nil).debug()
let two = BehaviorSubject<Int>(value: 0).debug()

// endless stream of events with identical values
Observable.combineLatest(one, two)
    .debounce(.milliseconds(10), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { ... })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// distinctUntilChanged breaks the cycle, but why?
Observable.combineLatest(one.distinctUntilChanged(), two.distinctUntilChanged())
    .debounce(.milliseconds(10), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { ... })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

one.onNext("a")
two.onNext(1)
```

Comment: With the code shown, both combineLatest would fire exactly once, unless there are successive emissions with the same values, in which case the first combineLatest would fire but the second with distinctUntilChanged would not. So maybe the problem is somewhere in the code that is not shown here and where onNext is executed multiple times on the BehaviorSubjects with same value?

Answer (score 0):

In running this code, here is what I see...

Both of the `combineLatest` calls emit the same sequence of values.

```
subscribed
Event next((nil, 0))
Event next((Optional("a"), 0))
Event next((Optional("a"), 1))
```

This makes complete sense. The combineLatest operator subscribes to `one` which emits a `.next(nil)` then it subscribes to `two` which emits a `.next(0)` so it emits a `next((nil, 0))`, then you call `onNext("a")` on `one` so the combineLatest emits a `next((Optional("a"), 0))` and lastly you call `onNext(1)` on `two` and combineLatest emits a `next((Optional("a"), 1))`.

Whatever problem you are having has nothing to do with the code you posted.